# mvc view is not populating with data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to populate a view from a controller. Here is what I am trying to do. I am filling in a dictionary with data and then I am putting that data in a viewdata:

```
  Dictionary<string, string> list = ExtractURL(content);
                ViewData["List"] = list;
```

At the view side I am having this:

```
  <ul>
    <% foreach(var item in ViewData["List"] as Dictionary<string, string>) { %>

    <li><% item.Value.ToString(); %></li>
    <% } %>
    </ul>
```

Now, everything runs ok, but at the end I am just getting the list without any data there. Check the screenshot for reference. 
Can someone please maybe point me what am I doing wrong.
Thanks in advance, Laziale[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your syntax, change `<% item.Value.ToString(); %>` to `<%= item.Value.ToString() %>`

Otherwise `ToString` will be called but not written to the output stream.

Comment: nevermind, it worked with the equal sign :). Thanks. Can I ask you one more question, I want that list to be populated with hyperlinks which will be clickable and with proper text inside. What should I modify so they can become hyperlinks instead, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: or `<%:` to add Html Encoding.

Comment: You have to start the tag with `<%=` (or `<%:` as Henk pointed out).